# CURL Required parameter not supplied

Tags: php, docker, curl, php-curl

Good Morning

when I run the follwing php script (generated by postman)

http://server:8088/api/generate_process_svg

on my debian Subsystem (win10) I get a "svg" file as response

```
<?php
$file_dot = 'statemachine_5.dot';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://server:8099/viz.svg',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('dot'=> new CURLFILE($file_dot)),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

But when I run the same Script in an container using php:7.4.1-apache I get

```
{"errors": {"dot": "Required parameter 'dot' not supplied"}}
```

I have no clue why .. different CULR versions?
Dot file exist in the same folder ...

```
root@xxx:/var/www/html/api# ls -la 

-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 522 Apr 24 06:46 generate_process_svg.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 445 Apr 24 06:35 statemachine_5.dot

root@xx:/var/www/html/api#
```

Thanks for help
rob

runnning

docker run -d -p 8099:8000 --name graphviz sseemayer/graphviz

docker run -d -p 8088:80 --name webserver php:7.4.1-apache

on Server

this is the dot file

```
digraph G { rankdir="LR"node [shape=box]"booked (27)" -> "booked (27)""booked (27)" -> "prepared (28)""booked (27)" -> "canceled (85)""prepared (28)" -> "prepared (28)""prepared (28)" -> "participated  (29)""prepared (28)" -> "canceled (85)""participated  (29)" -> "participated  (29)""participated  (29)" -> "succeeded (31)""participated  (29)" -> "failed (32)""participated  (29)" -> " NOT graded (157)""participated  (29)" -> "cheated (158)"}
```

Comment: How are you building and running the client container?  Does the `statemachine_5.dot` file exist inside the container?

Comment: Hi david
I just run the container and don't build it by myself ... 
YES statemachine_5.dot exist inside the container in teh www-root - actually I  use a volumen and docker compose - that is why I added the "ls -la" result to show the php script and the statemachine_5.dot are in the same folder in the webroot of the php:7.4.1-apache container ...